# Command not found when using bash script to ssh remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to write a bash script and I am a newbie at that.

Everything is working beside the thing that some particular command are giving me the error

```
./start_components1.sh: line 17: cmd1: command not found
```

They are some specific commands of my machine and I think they are related somehow to the thing that when I ssh, through the bash script, into the machine the environment is not loaded. I could be wrong.

Anyway, what happens is that if I ssh normally into my machine from a terminal and then execute the command it works flawlessly.

When I try to do the same through a bash script it tells me command not found.

I googled a lot and tried different things. Nothing worked.

Here my script if it can help:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=odroid

while getopts r:d:p:f: option
do
 case "${option}"
 in
 r) ROBOT=${OPTARG};;
 esac
done

for HOSTNAME in ${ROBOT}; do    
    ssh -l ${USERNAME} "robot${HOSTNAME}" "./start_components${HOSTNAME}.sh; ls"    
done
```

**EDIT**: I thought it was working After following the hint by @PauloScardine I also realized that the permissions of my file were not set to executable so I `sudo chmod +x fileToExecute` 
I thought this solved my problem but: 
It is still not working. The command are executed without any error (it seems) but they are not really executed. Example: if I go in ssh (without bash script) on my machine and I do `/opt/openrobots/bin/pom-ros` I see that my component I want to launch is launched, I get some output and so on. When I launch the `start_components2.sh` file which should launch `/opt/openrobots/bin/pom-ros` I do not see any output and I am sure that the component is not launched because I have no effect :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess `cmd1` is not in `$PATH` when you run a session without a tty which is probably what ssh is doing. Have you tried to put the full path to `cmd1` in `./start_components${HOSTNAME}.sh`?

Comment: Hi @PauloScardine I did try now and it gives me another error: 
`permission denied` . 

Usually I do not use `sudo ./start_components2.sh` so why it is telling me I am not allowed? 

Thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: add `set -x;export PS4='$LINENO >'` as the 2nd line of your `./start_components2.sh`. You can then see what is being executed for each line. Good luck.

Comment: And please delete excess comments that are now included in your Q. Good luck.

Comment: What happens if you hardcode the command in your script, eg `ssh -l ${USERNAME} "robot${HOSTNAME} "/opt/openrobots/bin/pom-ros"`?

Answer (score 1):

The ssh command is normally found in the $PATH variable that's why from anywhere you can type on your STDIN "ssh user@host". But inside a script the environment variables may not have been made available.

You can fix this by
`/bin/ssh user@host`

Depending on your linux flavor, you may have to change the absolute path of the ssh command. From any shell you can type `which ssh` to find this path.

Answer (score -1):

Command not found usually means, that it cannot find it in the current directory as you used a dot for execution.

Try to put a full path to the script. Something like:

```
ssh -l ${USERNAME} "robot${HOSTNAME}" "/home/${USERNAME}/start_components${HOSTNAME}.sh; ls"
```

However this will only work when the script start_componets will be in home directory of the user behind ${USERNAME} variable

Comment: The error message is about `cmd1`, not `start_components1.sh`.